# Electronics floating on high potential

Tags: high-voltage

Trying to make an adjustable current source floating on high potential.

Can someone explain why the driving logic should not be also on high potential?

I saw only the variants with minimum parts floating on HV. Driving signals for FET and analog feedback and faulty signal were via optic fiber.

What are the risks or benefits in comparison with having all driving logic floating and only one optic fiber for digital current adjustment?

Comment: Had a very nasty experience with a set of disco flashing lights once where the control logic was floating on the neutral Line. Hint..Never assume neutral is anywhere near ground potential.

Answer (score 1):

Having large amounts of circuitry floating on high voltage introduces safety and isolation concerns. You have to debug and maintain this stuff. If you can manage the safety issues and isolate it properly then I can  not see much of a problem.

You are in a better position to understand the benefits as you understand your application much better than us.

Comment: The main reason to keep as much of the control logic at ground (especially during development) is it's easier to debug etc. You are less likely to connect the HV to the ground lead of any oscilloscope (they are grounded through the crocodile test lead and the metal case ... unless some one has dangerously modified them) ... classic instruction  on how not to blow up your scope. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaELqAo4kkQ